# how to group reply messages to original message

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing replies in a separate table with the original message as the reference id. What I'm trying to do is when a message is clicked it grabs all the corresponding replies and displays them under the main message but how to get the corresponding messages?

This is what I've tried but can't find a `WHERE` clause that works. Is there any way to group these by the `to_id` and `from_id` and `reference_id` or am I on the wrong track all together?

Basic SQL is pretty much my ceiling at this point so any pointer appreciated.

replies table
[image]

MESSAGE TABLE
[image]

What I want to do is to have one main conversation with someone and if you message them once all further replies and/or new messages appear underneath

EXAMPLE:

```
MAIN MESSAGE to USER 1
//grouped by date and if a certain period passes block with a line
reply from user 2
reply from user 1
----------------------------
days later
new message from user 2
```

so on...

Comment: Please show us a sample result set that you want to get.

Comment: To be honest, you'll probably want to pull the data out with a `JOIN` and worry about grouping it in code later - trying to group in that kind of logic in `SQL` won't be fun, and can probably be handled more easily and efficiently in PHP than with a query. Use your database to store data and return, use your language of choice (guessing PHP based on PHPMyAdmin there) to process it and format it for output.

Comment: @phatskat Can I have an identifier that both users get when either one messages the other and store that in the db and call down the messages by that id? EDIT: I guess that would be the `reference_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT m.subject, r.Message, r.from_id, r.to_id FROM MESSAGE m
JOIN replies r on m.reply_id = r.id
WHERE ((m.from_id = `user_1_id` AND m.to_id = `user_2_id`)
OR (m.from_id = `user_2_id` AND m.to_id = `user_1_id`))
ORDER BY r.date_sent asc
```

Comment: I'm not sure either because my SQL is still in the beginning stages but the logic looks like it will give me what I'm trying to get. Thanks. Much appreciated. I need to research JOINS

Comment: Hope it helps and here is a visual representation of JOINS that is quite helpful http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? If you can provide the layout of both the messages and replies tables it may help...

```
SELECT 
    `messages`.`message`,
    `replies`.`reply`
FROM 
    `messages`
JOIN
    `replies` ON(`messages`.`id` = `replies`.`message_id`)
```